# How to open adb connect memu like emulator-xxxx (without tcpip)?

Tags: android, adb, bluestacks

[image: How to improve adb connection performance?]

I want multiple adb connection simultaneously. A connect adb not through localhost(tcpip). How to achieve them with memu or bluestack? I achieved them on ldplayer but ldplayer quite heavy.